# PowerPivot table relationship showing repeating Totals

Tags: excel, pivot, relationship, data-analysis, powerpivot

I have two different tables whereby one table has Invoice value whereas other table has additional charges. Both these tables have document number (Invoice no) in common.I have used this document number for relationship purpose. Using the relationship I want landed cost for each Invoice no. However, using the relationship, the totals are being repeated. I am attaching the images for quick reference.

I have attached the Snapshot in a single image file a) Source Data b)Desired Result c) What I got[Snapshot of source data, desired result & What i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6gxU.png)

Comment: Both links refer to the same image. please check and edit your question.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz the single image have it both. The desired result what I want & the result i got.

Answer (score 0):

In the last 3 columns instead of doing a sum do a max.

Comment: using max doesn't give a solution either. It would give the maximum value in last 3 columns.

Comment: your result deviates from your expected result by a measure of 4 times your expected result. The reason for this is your joining statement. You are joining each variable by itself the number of times it exists. I would have expected the max function to fix what you are doing. How are you exactly joining your sources to create your final table?

Comment: I have created two tables for two different data sources & using the document number as a common parameter in relationship option.